# Databases when uploading website?

Tags: database

I am creating a website offline on a local server, but trying to do it in such a way that if I ever do want to put it online **all** I have to do us upload one file to an actual server. I have been able to do most things I have wanted except use databases. So is there anyway that I can utilise a database such I can do the above?

Comment: Depends on web hosting. At least you have to configure database users/privileges.

Comment: @i486 I realise I will have to make some small tweaks here and there, I just don't want to have to edit any code or make new databases.

Comment: If your DB is MS SQL, you can upload .mdf and .ldf files and attach the DB at runtime. If it is MySQL, you can dump it in .SQL file locally and parse on server.